# How can I query a MySQL database from a Rails app without models?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I execute a SQL query from a Rails application to a MySQL database?

My application uses Postgres as a primary database, but I need to read some information from a secondary MySQL database. I can't create models because the MySQL database has more than 100 tables, named in an incompatible way for every table. Can it be done  without ActiveRecord or some other way?

Comment: Rails does support forcing table names for a particular model using `set_table_name "foo"`.  If the number of tables is static and it's likely that you'll use them all, I would start creating models in the order they're needed.  There is also support in AR:Base for specifying the primary key field.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use mysql2 gem directly. Read the documentation here: 
https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2

Or:

You can create a new class like MysqlConnection like this:

```
class MysqlConnection < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.establish_connection(:adapter => 'mysql', :database => 'some-database-name') # Set all the other required params like host, user-name, etc
end
```

From now on, you can do,

```
MysqlConnection.connection.select_all("SELECT * FROM table_name")
```

Follow the link to understand how to store the configuration details in database.yml: http://weare.buildingsky.net/2006/12/06/multiple-concurrent-database-connections-with-activerecord

Comment: Thank you for you answer! It's the best solution for me.